# Meaning of "convention" tag?

Tags: support, specific-question, tags

What does the `conventions` tag mean?

I assume it means *writing conventions*, but then it dawned on me that it might also refer to *conventions **about** writing*, kind of like Comic-Con but about writing. Not sure if any of those exist, and I highly doubt it does, but I'm curious and weird so I decided to ask about it on the off-chance in which I'd be wrong.

Comment: Writing conventions do exist. They are called "book fairs".

Comment: Oh. xD Haha, I didn't know that. Lol.

Comment: So what does the above tag refer to, then? xD

Comment: I guess it refers to what is conventional in writing, but I don't use tags on this site because I don't find them helpful, so I don't really know. I think you can click on the tag, if you see it somewhere, and then get all the questions tagged as "conventions" -- that should tell you what kind of questions the tag refers to. Like this: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know clicking on it will do that. Thank you. Why is it you don't use tags? I thought you have to if you want to ask a question.

Comment: I don't ask questions much, and if I do I just add some tags that seem to fit. But what I mean with "I don't use tags" is that I don't use them to find stuff. On Stack Overflow, where there is too much happening for me to take it all in, and where I have absolutely no understanding of much that is asked there, I usually just look into some of the things I know about by clicking on the relevant tags, so that, for example, I only see Qs related to PHP. Here, where there are very few new questions on any day, I look at everything and don't use the tags as filter.

Comment: Also, much of what has to do with writing is interrelated, and ordering the questions into different categories with tags doesn't always make much sense. For example, character development has to do with plot, because character is related to plot, so why would I want to file that question under character? Sure, I can use multiple tags, but why not just ask my question and have everyone look at it? Because, if you are a writer, you'll know about most everything that has to do with writing.